# How to create a postgresql (version 10) cluster and databases in this cluster (Ubuntu)?

Tags: database, postgresql, cluster-analysis, ubuntu-18.04

I would like to create a cluster of databases with Postgresql (version 10) locally in my machine (Ubuntu). So, I would like to know how to create a cluster. Then, I would like to create a database in this cluster and add some data from a given csv file.
I had a look at some tutorials on the web, but it's not really easy to understand.
I know that I have to use `initdb` command, but I get command not found error while running it.
Can someone explain me how to do this task ? I would really appreciate any help.

P.s. I've just seen on the web that I should use `pg_createcluster` rather than `initdb` which is not activate by default in the path. So, I would be able to create a cluster but I would really appreciate an example to be sure I am doing right things.

Comment: You can either reference the executables by absolute path or add the containing directory to the `PATH` environment variable. That will remove the obstacle. Other than that, follow the documentation rather than obscure tutorials.

Comment: Thanks I am now able to create a cluster but I do not find anything to specify that I want to create a given database in that cluster and insert csv data into. Do you have any sources that may help ?

Comment: [The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-createdb.html) contains what you need.

Comment: This doesn't show me how to create a database in a specific cluster. I mean I would like to create a db in a cluster a and another db in a cluster b. The documentation just shows us how to create a db but there is no explanation about what I want to do.

Comment: Sure it does. If you read the documentation for [`createdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html), you will see that it has options to specify the host and port of the cluster where you want to create the database.

Comment: My bad.. I did not look that page. In case host is my own machine should I let the default value ? Let me look at the pg_clustercreate options to see how to set those parameters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207073/discussion-between-mistapopo-and-laurenz-albe).